# How do you constrain input delay for a multidimenionsal input vector?

Tags: synthesis, asic, chip-design, constraints, sdc

I am defining SDC input constraints for synthesis of a small module that is part of a larger ASIC design. I plan to run the module through synthesis using Synopsys tools. A few of the inputs to this module are multidimensional arrays. For example:

```
input signed [15:0] data_x [3:0][1:0],
```

`data_x` is a 3 dimensional vector.

For a vector such as

```
input signed [15:0] data_y,
```

to define the input delay, the constraint would be

```
set_input_delay -clock [get_clock clk] 5000 [get_ports data_y\[*\]]
```

However, for a multidimensional array input, the following wildcard setup does not appear to match the inputs:

```
set_input_delay -clock [get_clock clk] 5000 [get_ports data_x\[*\]\[*\]\[*\]]
```

The following works, but matches other internal signals in the design( such as `data_x_d`, which is undesirable):

```
set_input_delay -clock [get_clock clk] 5000 [get_ports data_x*]
```

Is there a way to specify the name with a wildcard to correctly identify all ports in a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `-regexp` option for `get_posts`. Try:

```
set_input_delay -clock [get_clock clk] 5000 [get_ports -regexp data_x\[\d+\]\[\d+\]\[\d+\]]
```

You can get bus ports by their base name. Not sure it it works on multi-dimensional arrays. So this might also work:

```
set_input_delay -clock [get_clock clk] 5000 [get_ports data_x]
```